Intersecting by largest area with GeoPandas
I intersect by the largest area as a filter and then merge.
Then I used GeoPandas 0.14.
overlay_gdf = left.overlay(right, keep_geom_type=True, how="intersection")

overlay_gdf = (
    overlay_gdf.assign(area=lambda x: x.geometry.area)
    .sort_values(by="area", ascending=False)
    .groupby("OBJECT_UUI")
    .first(skipna=False)
    .drop(columns=["area", "geometry"])
    .merge(left, left_index=True, right_on="OBJECT_UUI")
)

return gpd.GeoDataFrame(overlay_gdf)

What I am wondering about is, that I got rare cases of duplication.
Hence, I want to ask, given that the intersected areas with the same "OBJECT_UUI" have the same size, what will happen? Will it select one of the entries randomly, or select both?
I do this spatial join twice, to combine three tables.
There seem to be about 350 duplicated areas per 1 million results.

Accourding to this  comment:

The documentation points to np.ndarray.sort for info on the
algorithms.

ndarray.sort:

When a is an array with fields defined, this argument specifies which
fields to compare first, second, etc. A single field can be specified
as a string, and not all fields need be specified, but unspecified
fields will still be used, in the order in which they come up in the
dtype, to break ties.

So when you sort, groupby first, when duplicates are found it sounds like all other columns are used in sorting. The duplicates will then be dropped.
If you want to be sure which row is kept you could add column and use in the sorting.
For example like:
gdf["temp"] = range(gdf.shape[0])

overlay_gdf.assign(area=lambda x: x.geometry.area)
    .sort_values(by=["area", "temp"], ascending=False)
    .groupby("OBJECT_UUI")
    .first(skipna=False)
    .drop(columns=["area", "geometry", "temp"])

